# Concatenate two lists in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I set myself to the task to write a Common Lisp function that concatenates two lists without using `append`.

Common Lisp input `(concat-lists '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))` should return `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`

Even though my solution seems to work it looks overtly complicated

```
(defun concat-lists(seq1 seq2)
    (cond ((not (null seq1)) (cons (car seq1) (concat-lists (cdr seq1) seq2)))
          (T (cond ((not (null seq2)) (cons (car seq2) (concat-lists seq1 (cdr seq2))))
                   (T nil)))))
```

What I'm looking for is a more elegant solution using `reduce` where I use  `seq1` as initial value and then apply a function to each element of `seq2`, thereby appending each value of the list to `seq1`. Somehow I always get stuck when trying....

Any help or input is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CL-USER 39 > (reduce #'cons
                     '(1 2 3 4 5)
                     :initial-value '(a b c d e)
                     :from-end t) 
(1 2 3 4 5 A B C D E)
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution of Rainer Joswig is really elegant and simple, and respects your request of using `reduce`.

If you want to see also a recursive, simple solution, then here is the classical one:

```
(defun concat-lists (seq1 seq2)
  (if (null seq1)
      seq2
      (cons (car seq1) (concat-lists (cdr seq1) seq2))))

(concat-lists '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 4):

I do understand your requirement for 'reduce'. and here other options:

CL also has 'concatenante'

`(concatenate 'list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))`

There is also the other less complicated (IMHO), and not as elegant.

`(defun concat-lists (list1 list2)
     (let ((a (copy-list list1))
           (b (copy-list list2)))
        (rplacd (last a) b)
         a))`

or

`(defun concat-lists (list1 list2)
     (let ((a (copy-list list1))
           (b (copy-list list2)))
        (nconc a b)))`

Comment: There is no need to copy `list2` in both your functions, since it will not be modified.